# why Can't pickle a defauldict of objects in python?

Tags: python, object, serialization, pickle, defaultdict

I have a `defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(list))` which I want to serialize then deserialize. The problem is that I am getting the following error and I really don't know what should I do to fix it. I am using python 2.7 and ubuntu 16.04.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test_preprocessing.py",
>   line 51, in 
>       pickle.dump(flights, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute
>   lookup **builtin**.function failed

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from collections import defaultdict
import cPickle as pickle

class Flight(object):
    def __init__(self, DDATE, WEEK_PERIOD, DPERIOD, RPERIOD, ALLIANCE, FARE):
            self.DDATE       = DDATE
            self.WEEK_PERIOD = WEEK_PERIOD
            self.DPERIOD     = DPERIOD
            self.RPERIOD     = RPERIOD
            self.ALLIANCE    = ALLIANCE
            self.FARE        = FARE

class Key(object):
    def __init__(self, DDATE, WEEK_PERIOD, DPERIOD, RPERIOD, ALLIANCE):
            self.DDATE       = DDATE
            self.WEEK_PERIOD = WEEK_PERIOD
            self.DPERIOD     = DPERIOD
            self.RPERIOD     = RPERIOD
            self.ALLIANCE    = ALLIANCE

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.DDATE, self.WEEK_PERIOD, self.DPERIOD, self.RPERIOD, self.ALLIANCE))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.DDATE, self.WEEK_PERIOD, self.DPERIOD, self.RPERIOD, self.ALLIANCE) == (other.DDATE, other.WEEK_PERIOD, other.DPERIOD, other.RPERIOD, other.ALLIANCE)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        # Not strictly necessary, but to avoid having both x==y and x!=y
        # True at the same time
        return not(self == other)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    flight = Flight("", "","","", "", "")
    key    = Key("", "", "", "", "")
    flights = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(list))

    flights[key][20].append(flights)
    f = open('flights.pkl', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(flights, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    f.close()

    f = open('flights.pkl', 'rb')
    flights = pickle.load(f)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Try not using a `lambda`. Pickle does not play well with `lambda`'s.

Comment: hey man what's up. you saved me. thank you. flights = defaultdict(partial(defaultdict, list))